# changing the position of textbox using code

Tags: vb.net, apache-flex, textbox, grid, location

In my form I have an AXVS Flex Grid and a Textbox. Firstly the textbox will not be visible.

When the focus is on a particular column of the flexgrid, the textbox will be visible and the Flex Grid will be disabled. The position of the text box will be at the bottom of the particular row at the first time.

But when another row is inserted, then I need to change the position of the textbox to the bottom of the new row and so on.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Position of a control can be retrieved and set using the Top & Left properties of the control.
So you can get the Top,Left property of the inserted row and set the Top,Left property of TextBox accrodingly.

e.g.

```
TextBox1.Top = InsertedRow.Top +=10
TextBox1.Left = InsertedRow.Left
```

This will bring the textbox below inserted row.